# Will a multi-sized favicon .ico file impact web page loading speed?

Tags: html, performance, browser, favicon, .ico

We used a favicon converter to create multiple image sizes within one .ico file for our website. I am concerned because our new .ico is now 1.6 KB and I don't know if internet browsers will load all of the various image sizes or only the image sizes that they need?

This code is now in the head of all of our web pages:

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://example.com/images/favicon.ico"/>
```

Because the code is in the head it will be one of the first things that the browser loads before it proceeds to load the rest of each web page.

I am also worried about getting penalized via the Google Caffeine update if we have now significantly increased our page load times for the average browser.

Does anyone know if browsers selectively upload only the image size that they need from the .ico file (small 16 by 16 image)? Or if they in fact upload the entire .ico file (all 1.6 KB)?

Comment: No browser I'm aware of will take the trouble of implementing partial download for an *.ico file (if that's even possible as per the file format).

Comment: I appreciate everyone's answers - ultimately I just want to know the answer - that's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.6 KB is fine for a favicon. You shouldn't run into any speed problems with that. Most browsers (I believe) will just resize the file that you have... you could make it smaller, if you want, but it should be fine as it is.

Also, remember that most users (the ones that don't regularly clear their cache) will only have to load the icon once (i.e. the first time they go to your page), after that, it's temporarily saved to their computer for faster load times.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The favicon file is always fully downloaded. However, 1.6KB is not that big. If you could get it to 1.4Kb, it would fit one IP packet, and therefore it would have nearly no impact on your page speed.
If you want to do your best, try using only a 16x16 favicon, and using `<link rel="">..` links to provide alternatives for better browsers (mobile phones with retina, those beasts)
The favicon will be used by older browsers as a fallback, and other, more advanced ones will use whatever PNG you provide in the `<link>` sections.